# WPF multidimensional int array in ItemsControl with TwoWay

Tags: wpf, multidimensional-array, itemscontrol, two-way-binding

I have a multidimensional int array (vectors) which I want to display in a `ItemsControl` with `TextBox` as `DataTemplate`. I use `Binding` to a `VectorList` which is a List< int[] >. int[,] did not work, because `ItemSource` has to be one-dimensional, so I converted it to List< int[] >.

This `Binding` to `VectorList` works `OneWay`, the `TextBoxes` are all shown correctly. However `TwoWay` does not work, the `ItemSource` of the `ItemsControl` does not change and the `VectorList` is not updating. What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" ItemsSource="{Binding VectorList, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="35" Width="40"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Okay, I just use a Grid now and read/set the TextBoxes manually. Much easier and it works :)

Comment: I also stucked up with `Int[]` to Checkboxes 0 - false, 1 - true. It is readonly but It is not updating the Source `Int[]`. Why?? and it is the Same `ItemsControl` binding..